# War file not getting executed in tomcat

Tags: rest, tomcat

I am new to web application development.

I have been working on developing a rest web service and deploying it locally on apache tomcat server. I am using sts for this.

Now, when I am executing my application from sts (Run as java application).
It is running fine. I am hitting the url at localhost:8080 and everything is fine.

Now, I am doing the following :

1. Created a .war file for my application, named sample-rest-service.war
2. On a different system, I have downloaded and installed tomcat 8 configured to run on port 9999
3. I copy my .war file in the webapps folder of apache-tomcat-8.028
4. I start my tomcat server using startup.sh
5. I type localhost:9999 in my browser and the home page appears
6. I type localhost:9999/sample-rest-service, but I get the error message with code 404
7. I type localhost:9999/examples and it works fine, i.r. content appears
8. I check the webapps folder, .war file has been extracted both war file and the extracted folder are present there.

What am I missing ?

Normally if I run my application through sts, I do this :

1. Run as Java Application
2. Then it asks me to chose, I chose Application-hello, where Application is the class having main() and hello is the package
3. After that in the console I can read the message that Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
4. Now in my browser I type this  : http://localhost:8080/greeting
5. I get the output in JSON

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>sample-rest-service</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

To generate war I did the following :

1. Added the maven war plugin in my project
2. changed the packaging in pom.xml from jar(default) to war
3. Export war file

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>                            
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: What appears in your Tomcat access log?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen there are many log files inside the logs folder - catalina.date.log, catalina.out, host-manager.log, manager.log, localhost.log, localhost-access.log.  Which one is the relevant one ?

Comment: What does `localhost-access.log` say?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2015:14:36:10 +0530] "GET /sample-rest-service HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2015:14:36:10 +0530] "GET /sample-rest-service/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1034
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Oct/2015:14:36:38 +0530] "GET /sample-rest-service/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1034

Comment: How did you generate your WAR file?  Also, please post your `web.xml` file.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please check the edits

Comment: You never defined any servlets in your `web.xml` which should run in your web application.  When you navigated to `http://localhost:8080/greeting` Tomcat is showing you the default home page, which apparently contains some JSON content.  And by the way, you also appear to have not configured your Tomcat to run on port 9999.

Comment: On my system, I have sts, where tomcat is already built in, that is running on 8080. Here my web service is running. But when I create a war deploy on a different system, which has a different tomcat configured on 9999, I am getting 404 error

Comment: At this point I'd recommend that you work through a J2EE tutorial.  It will be very hard for you to learn J2EE through this single question.

Comment: I appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: The reason I suggest a tutorial is that the main purpose of using a Java WAR is the ability to run servlets on your server.  You don't even have any of these, so the question comes off as being a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the whole problem was with building the war file.

The proper way to build a deployable and runnable war file through sts is explained [**here**](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)

1. Extend your Application class with SpringBootServletInitializer, and override the configure method

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
       return application.sources(Application.class);
   }
   ```
2. In pom.xml, mention war inside packaging tags
3. you need to mark the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependencies as “provided”